# get Token from asp.net core 3

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core, axios, token

I try to get a token in react native  with axios from net core3, but I won't succeed in addressing the post method? Or do I have trouble writing the function?

```
function Test() {
   const [name, setname] = useState('')
   const [mobile, setmobile] = useState('')
   const post = () => {
      axios.post('http://apiaddres.ir/Token', {
         name: name,
         mobile: mobile,
      }).then((response) => {
         console.log(response.config)
      })
   }
   return (
      <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
         <TextInput
            placeholder='name'
            onChangeText={(event) => setname(event)}
         />
         <TextInput
            placeholder='phone'
            onChangeText={(event) => setmobile(event)}
         />
         <Button onPress={() => post()}>
            <Text>click</Text>
         </Button>
      </View>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the incorrect method of query. Here is the sample.

If you use a standalone react, url is a absolute path and the parameter shoulbe be as a string.

```
axios.post('http://apiaddres.ir/Token?name=nm&mobile=mobible')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data)
        })
```

An another way to send parameter (if you use asp.net core react template).

```
axios.post('/Token', {
     name: name,
     mobile: mobile,
  }).then((response) => {
     console.log(response.data)
  })
```

The `config` is not a property of `response`.

Ensure the server is a correct post method.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult get(string name,string mobile)
    {
        return Ok($"{name},{mobile}");
    }
}
```

Ensure the server has enabled **cors** and does't have any validation or authentication on the post method. Then it can address the post method.

[image]